# Assistence: "Continuous functions and oscillations on an interval"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I hope it is going well for you. I am experiencing some serious trouble with the following problem and am unsure of where to start. I have included some ideas that I have had down below.

**Problem**

Let the function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We want to prove that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists points $a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsm < x_n = b$ such that $\omega_f ([x_i, x_{i+1}]) < \epsilon$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n-1$.

(Note that $\omega_f ([x_i, x_{i+1}]) = \underset{x\in [x_i, x_{i+1}]}{\text{sup }}f(x) - \underset{x\in [x_i, x_{i+1}]}{\text{inf }}f(x)   = \underset{x,y\in [x_i, x_{i+1}]}{\text{sup}}|f(x) - f(y)|$)

**Thoughts**

I was thinking about using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, i.e. given $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in A$, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that whenever  $|x-x_0| < \delta$ for some $x\in A$ it follows that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$, to show that each $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $x,y\in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n-1$ but am stuck, generally speaking. Perhaps unfirom continuity could come into play. I also read somewhere that $f$ is only continuous at $c$ (in my case this would be $x_0$) if $\omega_f(c)=0$.

Comment: This might be rather easy if you are permitted to use theory of Riemann integration. Your $f$ is Riemann-integrable, and you could take a look at the necessary "Riemann condition".

Comment: @311411 Unfortunately, I am not permitted to do so. Thank you for this suggestion though; in learning about Riemann integration I can return to this problem and resolve it. But for now I think I must solve it through the definitions of continuity and uniform continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thought to use uniform continuity is correct. In particular, since $[a, b]$ is compact,  $f$ is uniformly continuous, so we can find a $\delta$ so that if $|x - y| \leq \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. Then, if we let $x_0 = a, x_1 = a + \delta, x_2 = a + 2\delta, ..., x_{n - 1} = a + (n - 1)\delta, x_n = b$ with $a + n\delta \geq b$, then we have that $|x_n - x_{n + 1}| = \delta$ . So, if $x, y \in [x_{i}, x_{i + 1}]$ then $|x - y| < \delta$, so by our uniform continuity, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. See if you can show that this implies that
$$\left|\sup_{x \in [x_i, x_{i + 1}]}f(x) - \inf_{x \in[x_{i}, x_{i + 1}]}f(x)\right| < \varepsilon$$

Hint: Extreme value theorem makes this very easy. If your course has not proven the EVT, then directly think about the definition of sup and inf to realize that you can find a sequence $x_n : f(x_n) \to \sup_{x \in [x_i, x_{i + 1}]}f(x)$, and a sequence $y_n : f(y_n) \to \inf_{x \in[x_{i}, x_{i + 1}]}f(x)$ (why?). Then, notice that $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| < \varepsilon$ for any $n$. What happens when you take the limit?

Comment: Good stuff. by the way, this is essentially how to begin a short proof that $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: This is looking pretty awesome. I can't believe I didn't follow the compactness breadcrumbs and proceed down that route. I've upvoted this answer but will wait to check it so that others are motivated to answer (this is the answer I will likely check). Also, I am going to take a short break, but will try to follow your hint when I work on this problem again. I do not yet have EVT in my tool kit and will report back to you with any questions once I proceed with my proof. Thank you for time, you've furthered my understanding of math, and I am grateful for that.

Comment: @NicholasPriebe Just spent some time look over this more. Q1: Why is it necessary to have $a + n\delta \geq b$ instead of $a + n\delta = b$? Q2: attempt at finishing proof: "...so by our uniform continuity we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. Since $x, y \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$ was arbitrary, we have that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ holds for all $x, y \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$, which means we can write $\underset{x,y\in  [x_i, x_{i+1}]}{\text{sup}} |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$, as desired. Q3: Is it necessary to write "fix $0 \leq i \leq n-1$" before I begin with "now choose any $x, y \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$?

Comment: Your proof is slightly incorrect namely, you should have a $\leq$ in your final equality. The set $\{0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999...\}$ has every element strictly less than $1$, but the sup is equal to $1$. Even if $\forall a \in A, a < \varepsilon$, you can have $\sup(A) = \varepsilon$, so you should turn your $<$ into a $\leq$, and then your conclusion will be true. Answer for your $n\delta$ question in another comment, because it didn't fit here.

Comment: The reason I allow $\geq$ is that this way, you don't need to choose a $\delta$ such that $b - a$ is an integer multiple of $\delta$. It's very quick to prove you can do this, but I didn't feel like including that; my way, you just choose any $\delta$ that works, and it's possible that the last interval might be length less than $\delta$, or it might be exactly equal. This way, I didn't need to worry about selecting a $\delta$ which worked nicely with $b - a$.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; thank you again for your thoroughness. Your comments on the nonexistence of $\leq$ in my finishing proof along with the addition of $\leq$ for the $b \leq  a + n\delta$ statement both make sense to me now. Hope you have a nice night / day wherever you are!